# Items in SharePoint List can only be seen by the initiator and the approver

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

We would like to define a Workflow in SharePoint list that, hide all the items and allow the items to be seen only by the Workflow initiator (Item recorder) and the approver and the items that have been recorded and approved by other user are hidden.

Comment: How are you setting the initiator and approver for each item?

Comment: The Initiator the one that initiate the Workflow (The item Creator) and the approver is choosen by this initiator, he have th choice to assign the task of approval to who he want.

Comment: Ok then why can't you create a view which filters `[Created]=[Me] OR [Approver]=[Me]`

Comment: Thx we will try

Comment: It Works!! thx, but now we need a restriction to allow the users to change view, what is the permission that we have to delete?

Comment: You mean you want users to modify the view or restrict any modification?

Comment: To restrict any modification

Comment: You can just give `Contribute` permission on the list.

Comment: Thx everything is ok... nice job

Comment: OK cool I will post these as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view with following filters

`[Created]` = `[Me]`
   `Or`
   `[Approver]` = `[Me]`

Then provide only `Contribute` permission to the users so they won't modify the view.

Comment: But can't creators and approvers still find other items using Search? You've only hidden items from view, not restricted access.